# How to consume Web Api based on Json using Asp MVC 5?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, web-services, api

I am new in Asp Mvc so i have no idea how to do this ?

i am using an recharge api so i want to pass some data in url and want to get back response.

if i run this web api url in browser recharge successfully to on respectively mobile number. so i want to get recharge successfully or not.

Api Url :

```
https://www.example.com/recharge?api_token=token&number=123456789&amount=10
```

Code :

```
 public ActionResult Recharge()
 {
    string url =
                        "https://www.example.com/recharge?api_token=token&number=123456789&amount=10";
                    client = new HttpClient();
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    var response = ConsumeApi(2);
return View();
}

    public async Task<String> ConsumeApi(int id)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var responseData = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    return responseData;
                }
                return "wrong";
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to await the call to consumeApi? Because this is async your view is potentially returned before the call completes

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = await ConsumeApi(2);
return Json(response);
```

I changed your response to json so you could inspect the respons in the browser when you call your method.